# Compare columns in two tables

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

In ODI mapping, how can I compare source and target tables? I need to compare col1 (the source table) with col1 (the target table) row by row. If the target table differs from source, then update the target table (the same column and same row), else check the next row. Which component should I use and how?

Comment: Check `merge` command in oracle.

Comment: @Utsav , any more details or an example to show how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below sample:

*table1*: Target table 
*table2*: Source table

```
 MERGE INTO table1 t1 USING table t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t1.value = t2.value
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (id, value) values (t2.id, t2.value);
```